# What's wrong with this Vim mapping?

Tags: regex, vim, mapping, key-bindings, comments

Inside a function I use to initialise some TeX related settings I have the following mapping defined:

```
vmap <buffer> ucm :s/^\% //<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

I expected it to allow me to easily uncomment visually selected lines. The analogous:

```
vmap <buffer> cm :s/^/\% /<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

does a pretty nice job in commenting. Also analogous mappings for other languages, which use a #, and not a % work just fine. Those last ones look like this:

```
vmap <buffer> cm :s/^/# /<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
vmap <buffer> ucm :s/^# //<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

A sequence of <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>10</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>cm</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>10</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ucm</kbd> is supposed to leave the code intact.

So now: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding unecessary stuff.

```
:s/^/% <CR>
```

and

```
:s/^% /<CR>
```

should work for commenting and uncommenting respectively.

The third `/` is used to add options such as `/c` for "confirm" or `/g` for "global". If you don't use those options you don't need this `/` at all.

In your "uncomment" substitution you are escaping `%` but `%` in itself has no special meaning for Vim's regex flavour. Not only Vim is certainly not going to match it if it's escaped but `\%<something>` is used for a bunch of atoms like `\%d`. So your pattern fails because Vim stumbles upon your `\%` expecting the rest of the atom and getting "nothing".